# Can I disable the Insert key in the Delphi IDE?

Tags: delphi, insert, keyboard

Something I find really annoying is putting the Delphi editor into "type over mode" by pressing the <kbd>Insert</kbd> key, is there a way of disabling this behaviour in the Delphi IDE?

Comment: This is the way every text editor I've ever used works, including the box in which I am typing this message.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I've never found type-over mode useful in any editor, and whenever I've toggled it in Delphi I have to undo what I've typed over, go back to insert mode and do what I was intending to do.  I'm sure that some people find it useful - I'm just not one.  I guess it's like the people who disable the Caps lock key (which I do use occasionally)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write your own key binding for the code editor, to remap the keystroke.

There are a couple of examples of doing so included with Delphi itself. They're in your Samples folder; the exact location depends on your Delphi and Windows versions. In XE6 on Win7, for instance, see

> "C:\Users\Public\Public Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\14.0\Samples\Object Pascal\VCL\ToolsAPI\Editor KeyBinding"

In XE5, it's in

> "C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\12.0\Samples\Delphi\VCL\ToolsAPI\Editor KeyBinding".

And in D2007 look in

> "C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\5.0\Demos\DelphiWin32\VCLWin32\ToolsAPI\Editor KeyBinding".

With that being said, the behavior of the <kbd>Ins</kbd> in the Delphi Code Editor is the same behavior that the key has in every single text editor I've ever encountered (including those simple ones like Notepad.exe), going back to the days of MS-DOS and Edit.exe. If there's ever a chance that someone else will use your copy of the IDE, you're going to really tick them off if it doesn't act like a standard text editor/

Answer (score 8):

Get a table fork, insert it under the <kbd>Ins</kbd> key and pop it off.

When you have finished your Delphi editing session you can replace it.

:P

Comment: You shouldn't be bragging about the fact that your "highest scoring answer" was not one, but was a (not bad) attempt at humor that at best should have been a comment. It certainly doesn't qualify as an "answer" according to this site's usual quality standards.

Comment: @Ken White - absolutely right, Ken, but I wasn't bragging, I was being 'rueful'.  Although I was being flippant, the answer is still an effective solution to the OP's rather unusual request.

Comment: It's not an "effective solution", any more than "remove the engine and take it in the house with you" would be an effective solution for preventing your car from being stolen. (And your "solution" does not disable the functionality of the Ins key in Delphi's editor; it disables the functionality for *every application*, which wasn't what the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can!! But you have to make the change system wide.

Follow the instructions from [this](https://superuser.com/questions/31794/windows-insert-key-anti-functionality-accidentally-triggers-how-to-stop-it-perm) question:

> 1. Go to **Start → Run → regedit**
> 2. Go to **HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard
>      Layout**
> 3. Right-click on the right half of the screen and choose **New → Binary
>      Value**
> 4. Name the new value **Scancode Map**
> 5. Enter **000000000000000002000000000052E000000000**
> 6. Close regedit
> 7. Reboot.

Then make sure that in Delphi IDE; **Tools → Options → Editor Options → Insert Mode** is `Enabled`.