# How do I disable the insert key so that it won't work with the C++ Builder IDE in XE8?

Tags: delphi, c++builder, delphi-xe8

I find the Insert key (specifically the overwrite mode) to be worse than useless.

So, I have disabled the Insert key Windows-wide (Windows 10) by using RegEdit, and remapping the key, in this way https://superuser.com/questions/31794/windows-insert-key-anti-functionality-accidentally-triggers-how-to-stop-it-perm .

This works for most programs, but doesn't work for the C++ Builder IDE (XE8).

I have looked at the answer given here

[Can I disable the Insert key in the Delphi IDE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24878401/can-i-disable-the-insert-key-in-the-delphi-ide)

but it doesn't seem to apply to XE8, as there no longer seems to be a 'KeyBinding' sample, and it's for Object Pascal, which I am not familiar with.

How do I disable the insert key for the C++ Builder IDE in XE8?

Comment: The solution works the same, whether the sample app exists there or not. Find the online samples for a prior version of Delphi and get the sample files from there. I'm pretty sure the sample apps for XE6 are available at the same online repo as those for XE8 (can't get there from here to be sure).

Comment: Can you summarize exactly what that solution is? As I say in the question, I don't use Object Pascal. It's not clear to me what exactly I would be doing with the proposed solution from the other link.

Comment: Here is a link to the Object Pascal sample code in question. http://sourceforge.net/p/radstudiodemos/code/HEAD/tree/branches/RadStudio_XE6/Object%20Pascal/VCL/ToolsAPI/

Comment: Look at the code in BufferList.pas. It's pretty straightforward, and there are clear samples of working with specific keys (see `procedure TClassicBinding.BackSpaceDelete`, for instance). (`TClassicBinding` implements the IDE's *New IDE Classic* key binding.)

Comment: Are you saying create a program using C++ Builder that will bind the keys based on the sample, and then run that program every time I start Windows?

Comment: No, I'm saying that the code I mentioned creates an add-in (in a package) to the RAD Studio IDE that can change the operation of the keyboard within the IDE itself. Build the package, install it like any other package (there's a sample package file there as well), and the IDE will load it automatically when it's started. See the documentation, topic *Tools API*, particularly *Extending the IDE using the Tools API*.

Comment: Are you saying I have to modify the code, then build it? Or simply build it? I am now looking for a screwdriver to remove the insert key ...

Comment: Use some common sense. The source file I described implements the IDE Classic keyboard behavior in the IDE. If the Insert key using that key mapping doesn't behave the way you'd like, clearly you would need to modify the code to change that behavior. Use that source file, write a binding for the key(s) you want to change, set the appropriate binding type (see `TClassicBinding.GetBindingType` - it's self-explanatory), modify the `Register` procedure to add your key binding. and build/install the package.

Comment: Common sense tells me to just remove the Insert key from the keyboard, which I just did and it took 30 seconds. It's interesting to know there's the ability to extend the IDE using a tools API, though - thanks for this.

Comment: When you get around to actually looking at the code, look at `TClassicBinding.ToggleInsertMode`. It's interesting to you. :-)

Comment: Wit is there really no other way to change the default key bindings that to make an IDE extension? If so does it means that IDE already has several such extensions registered to provide you with a chance to switch between few of available key binding setups that you can change in IDE options?

Comment: Why are you pressing the INSERT key?

Comment: @SilverWarior: No, there is no  other way to change the keyboard bindings. (You can hack through with an expert to change menu item hotkeys, but not basic keyboard functionality.) The *New IDE Classic* (available in Tools->Options->Editor->Key Mappings) is indeed such an extension, and the source for it is in the unit I reference in the previous comments (and available in the samples distributed with Delphi at least as late as XE6). The same unit also implements the *Buffer List* keyboard mapping available in the same options dialog.

Comment: @David, it's unintentional pressing, which of course means you start typing and then plough through a bunch of text accidentally. The remapping I made system-wide (but doesn't work with the IDE) just makes it so that the Insert key doesn't do anything (stays in insert mode regardless of whether the key is pressed).

Comment: As this is in fact a duplicate of the linked question, and it still applies whether the sample app is available in current versions of Delphi or not, and as it applies equally as well to C++ Builder as it does to Delphi (it's all the same IDE, and all extensions are done via Delphi packages), this should really be closed as a duplicate (there is no other possible answer). As my close vote swings a dupe hammer, I'll hold off doing so for now to give others a chance to weigh in. The comments link to the necessary source, and an answer containing that link would be inappropriate.

Comment: Perhaps you should invest in a better keyboard, where the Ins key isn't located so inconveniently. I've never once hit Ins by mistake on any of my Logitech wireless keyboards, and I have three of them I use regularly (one all day long at my job). Or just learn not to flail wildly at the keys while you're typing. :-)

Comment: I typically work on a laptop. It's the same problem with all Windows laptops I've owned.

Comment: (Insert key is close to Delete key, and various other keys that are regularly pressed.)

Comment: I'm curious as to what, exactly, people use overwrite mode for. I'm sure it's used somewhere, just not sure what, ever since ASCII pictures went out of style with BBS's and 300-bps modems in the 1980s (or whenever that was).

Comment: Overwrite mode used to modify aligned columns of numbers, say. You need an external keyboard.

Comment: @AnthonyBurg: I use overwrite mode to modify columns of numbers, like David, or repeating pieces of code or data which only differ in a few characters, but I also use it to modify comments (which are always in a frame of `//`, in my units) without upsetting the layout. Since my development keyboards don't have a readily accessible `Ins` key (one is a Mac, other is a laptop which requires me to press `Fn+Ins` or to use the numeric keypad), I'm fine with that. The Mac keyboard lets me use `Ctrl+V` to switch insert and overwrite, and `Cmd+V` to paste. Best of both worlds.

Comment: @David, I'm actually quite happy with my keyboard, now that the Insert key has been removed. The way I work isn't compatible with an external keyboard either way (highly mobile, don't like working at desks).

Comment: @Rudy, ya, Apple made the wise decision to remove the Insert key a long time ago. If only the Windows world would catch up (it tends to copy Apple a lot, so who knows). Having a Ctrl+V command to toggle overwrite mode seems more sensible to me, since the uses for overwrite are pretty boutique.